# Left justify the strings in wix

Tags: string, wix, windows-installer, wix3.8

I am creating a setup of my one .Net Application using WIX 3.8.
I am using strings variables for UI part.
But i am unable to justify the strings.
How can i achieve the it?

Below is the code sample:-

```
<Control Id="lbl" Type="Text" Text="!(loc.STR)" X="30" Y="200" Width="290" Height="50" />
```

Here the STR is defined as a localize variable:

`<String Id="STRDBDROP">
If you are having trouble seeing the Justify options, please make sure that the zoom on your computer is set to 100%. You can change the zoom using the Ctrl
</String>`

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are text controls left justified by default?

Comment: Text Control are not left justified..

Comment: I want to make them left justified..Although WIX provide RightAligned Property but not LeftAligned property at all..

Comment: Wouldn't RightAligned=false be LeftAligned? Perhaps I don't understand the question.